# How to solve problem "Must be a valid json" - Django + Vue js

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I try to create object in Django with vue js + axios but somehowe this not work for me. I try in two ways and always I see in vue dev tools empty data. When I fill the data model in vuedev tools I see "Invalid value "Must be a valid Json"".

First way. I create a view that return jsonresponse.

```
@login_required
def save_embed(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = SubmitEmbed(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        r = requests.get('http://iframe.ly/api/oembed?url='+ url + '&api_key=' + IFRAMELYKEY)
        data = r.json()
        serializer = EmbedSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            embed = serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
else:
    form = SubmitEmbed()

return render(request, 'embed/embedadd.html', {'form': form})
```

Template:

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['!!', '!!'],
  data () {
    return {
      url: "http://example.com"
    }
  },
methods: {

  formSubmit(e) {

e.preventDefault();
let currentObj = this;
this.axios.post('http://wege.local:8000/recipes/recipe/embed/add/', {
    url: this.url,
})
.then(function (response) {
    currentObj.output = response.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    currentObj.output = error;
});

}

}
    });
</script>
```

Form:

```
        <div id="app">
          !! url.title !!
        <form method="post" class="margin-bottom-25" @submit="formSubmit">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success-gradiant">Dodaj link</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

In the url field has been added v-model "url".

as you can see in the screenshot below, when I fill in the url field, nothing happend

[image: vue dev tools]

Second way is to create endpoint with rest framework in Django and then create templateview with code:

```
            <div id="app">
        <form method="post" class="margin-bottom-25" @submit="formSubmit">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Adres przepisu*</label>
                  <input type="url" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Url" v-model="embed.url">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Tytuł</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Title" v-model="embed.title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Description" v-model="embed.description">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Thumbnail_url</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Tthumbnail_url" v-model="embed.thumbnail_url">
                </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success-gradiant">Dodaj link</button>
        </form>
        !! embed.title !!
        !! embed.url !!
      </div>
```

Vue js:

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['!!', '!!'],
  data () {
    return {
        embed:{
            url: 'http://example.com',
            title: '',
            description: '',
            thumbnail_url: '',
        }
    }
  },
methods: {

  formSubmit(e) {

e.preventDefault();
let currentObj = this;
this.axios.post('http://wege.local:8000/recipes/embeds/', this.embed)
.then(function (response) {
    currentObj.output = response.data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    currentObj.output = error;
});

}

}
    });
</script>
```

In the second case the same problem, in vue tools the fields are still empty after completing the form.

Answer (score 1):

I think your response is okay.
When/where do you define or gloabally bind axios to `this`? You keep trying `this.axios`, which does not exist. More on Vue instance properties [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html).
Unless I'm missing where you bind this.axios...
You need to `import axios from "axios";` and do  `axios.post(...)`

To see if your request is going out, try looking at the network tab in dev tools and see the requests that go out with the data! I see you're using firefox, check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, it was not an import problem. It turned out that I put the code on the subpage instead of the main template, which caused an error.
It enlightened me when you wrote "When/where do you define or gloabally bind axios". :D

Comment: Great, happy to help!